# How to create a inter-interactive multi-user profile system in a Flask based Web App?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login, multi-user

database used: (sqlite3) {Flask SQLAlchemy}

Files description:

1. homepage : html page
2. login_page : html form page which takes in values like username/password
3. dashboard_page : html page which pulls out data from the database

I created a flask based web app, but up until now it is a single user based system (I haven't added auth measures yet.)

Like it has homepage -> Login Page -> dashboard page.

Now I want separate dashboard pages for separate users.
For Example: Fatima and Sana should see separate contents given that they are two separate users.

---

I seek basic guidance on where to start and what tools can be used to implement the forementioned steps.

Answer (score 0):

First, create the user model to store users' data
then,

1. create the user registration part
2. create the user log-in part
3. create the user account part
4. create the user log-out part
5. And last make every thing responsive and check that again and again

Comment: Can you provide some videos for me start with?

I have got first two points checked, I presume. How to create user account part?

Comment: It's hard to provide a video on this topic cause it is a little bit longer topic. it'll take 2-3 days to do this.
you have to 1 topic per day it'll help you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Update:
I have created a database and session based login/logout system. As of now it seems like i have that multi user thing under control.

Now I want to make the profiles interact with each other, for example: Fatima's profile should see a notification if Sana pushes some request.

Note: I dont seek to create chatting mechanism between the two.